# SQLite database currently in use?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I'm writing a C# program that accesses a database but others in the network also access the database. It is a SQLite database. Now I wanted to ask whether *it is possible to examine the SQLite database if someone just writes in it?*

I had thought that my program could trie to write to the SQLite DB and if someone other writes in the DB,  I get the warning "Access Denied".

But how could I implement this in C #?

I'm sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a different database: SQLite cannot handle concurrent write connection. Only concurrent reads.

SQLite is a good choice as embedded database for local/client storage but if you need connection from different threads/pcs you need a different solution as [Sql Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx).

If you have to use SQLite then you should set a mechanism that when writing catch the Access Denied Exception and automatically retrieve until a configurable timeout expires.

As stated in the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)

> When SQLite tries to access a file that is locked by another process, the default behavior is to return SQLITE_BUSY

Test for SQLITE_BUSY. Here's some pseudo-code to illustrate a solution:

```
while (continueTrying) {
   retval = sqlite_exec(db, sqlQuery, callback, 0, &msg);
switch (retval) {
  case SQLITE_BUSY:
    Log("[%s] SQLITE_BUSY: sleeping fow a while...", threadName);
    sleep a bit... (use something like sleep(), for example)
    break;
  case SQLITE_OK:
    continueTrying = NO; // We're done
    break;
  default:
    Log("[%s] Can't execute \"%s\": %s\n", threadName, sqlQuery, msg);
    continueTrying = NO;
    break;
}
}
return retval;
```

[SQLite MultiThreading Reference](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=MultiThreading)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is file-based, and as such it doesn't support multiple connections at the same time.

What you can do is to try to obtain a lock on the file, and if that fails you know someone else is using it and you can then show the user a message or maybe implement a retry mechanism that pauses for a couple of seconds and tries again etc.

Bottom line, concurrent usage of a Sqlite db file is not possible.

Comment: I thought that more people can read at the same time?
Only if someone is writing the file is blocked or?

Comment: @Sam concurrent read, lock write. I updated my answer with code example